# ¿Qué le gustaría cambiar sobre las elecciones de moderadores?

Tags: discusión, elecciones, anuncios

*Publicación Importada de Meta SE: [What would you like to change about moderator elections?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/396431/what-would-you-like-to-change-about-moderator-elections)*

### TL/DR

Estamos revisando las elecciones de moderadores con la comunidad para discutir lo que creen que se debe mejorar. [Puede rellenar este formulario](https://forms.gle/1aXHKCbMcyX6pY7WA) (esta en ingles) para indicar su interés; los seleccionados serán invitados a unirse al grupo de trabajo el 13 de febrero de 2024.

Llevamos bastante tiempo organizando elecciones de moderadores de la misma manera; Vemos una serie de cosas que creemos que podrían mejorarse tanto para la comunidad como para la forma en que los administradores de la comunidad manejan las elecciones de moderadores. Con eso en mente, es hora de dar un paso atrás y revisar el proceso electoral para que podamos actualizarlo donde sea necesario. Algo que nos gustaría dejar muy claro acerca de esta iniciativa es que no estamos tratando de venderles un resultado específico. Queremos hacer actualizaciones significativas al proceso electoral, pero queremos hacerlo con usted.

### Cómo funciona actualmente para los Community Managers.

Baste decir que nuestro proceso actual necesita cierta automatización, pero nuestro proceso electoral actual en general se ve así:

- Un equipo de mods se comunica con los administradores de la comunidad sobre la necesidad de una elección. Alternativamente, podemos comunicarnos debido a renuncias.
- Luego, los CM discuten con los mods la carga de trabajo, cuántos necesitan y la urgencia. (Lo ideal sería que también discutiéramos cosas como los objetivos de los equipos mod: ¿quieren ser más acogedores o más educativos, por ejemplo?)
- Los CM sopesan la necesidad con las necesidades electorales existentes y encuentran un momento para organizar una elección.
- Los CM programan la elección y asignan un CM para supervisarla.
- Los CM crean la página de elecciones
- Dependiendo del tipo de elección, se crea una publicación de anuncio.
- Comienza la recopilación de preguntas. Los CM tienen que presionar un botón para generar esta publicación, pero por motivos temporales, lo omitimos. Los CM deben estar atentos a estas publicaciones para monitorear las preguntas enviadas porque es común que ocurran travesuras aquí.
- La Fase de Nominación. Una automatización desencadena un anuncio de las elecciones. La comunidad solo puede enviar ocho preguntas. Si hay más que eso, los CM deben decidir cuáles no pasan el corte. Una vez decidido un cuestionario, debemos pulsar unos botones para generarlo y crear la sala de chat para la elección. Esta fase es bastante manual. Tenemos que volver a estar atentos a las travesuras y tratarlas en consecuencia. Tenga en cuenta que cuando se identifican travesuras, otros CM participan en el proceso para discutir qué se debe hacer, si es que se debe hacer algo, respecto de dichas travesuras. Un único CM nunca lo maneja sin ayuda.
- Si no hay suficientes (o ninguna) nominaciones, los CM a veces se comunicarán con los Mods para ver si están dispuestos a hablar con buenos candidatos para unirse. Si el número de candidatos es insuficiente, la elección se prolongará una semana.
  Si se trata de una elección provisional y finaliza la fase de nominación, esas personas son designadas.
- Si hay suficientes nominaciones, comienza la fase de votación. Esta es una fase automatizada, por lo que no requiere entrada de CM.
- Al final de la fase de votación, un CM presionará algunos botones que calculan los votos, anuncian los ganadores, reparten diamantes y envían un correo electrónico de bienvenida. Luego, los CM darán la bienvenida a los mods en los distintos espacios de mods.

### ¿Por qué estamos haciendo esto?

Primero, quiero compartir por qué queremos hacer algunos cambios ahora y algunas cosas que nosotros, como equipo de gestión de la comunidad, esperamos obtener de esto.

Como sabes, la red cuenta con ciento ochenta y dos sitios. No todos los sitios necesitan una elección anual; a veces, un sitio solo necesita uno y, a veces, un sitio necesita más de uno al año. Otras veces, es posible que no lo necesite durante un par de años. Las setenta y dos elecciones que celebramos en los últimos dos años nos mantuvieron bastante ocupados y, debido a nuestro sistema actual, nos resultaría difícil hacer muchas más si surgiera la necesidad sin quitarnos otras responsabilidades. Las elecciones de moderadores son una parte crucial de la red, pero consumen bastante tiempo del CM. Específicamente, los CM deben hacer cosas en momentos específicos para hacer avanzar las elecciones. Esto, entre otras acciones manuales que deben realizar los CM, hace que el manejo de las elecciones requiera mucho tiempo. Creemos que sería mejor dedicar tiempo a trabajar en otros proyectos que necesitan nuestra atención. Además, queremos darle a nuestras comunidades más autonomía y control para dictar las necesidades de moderación de su sitio en lugar de depender del equipo de CM para juzgar cuándo se necesitan moderadores y elecciones.

Algo que nos gustaría explorar más con la comunidad es la transición de la programación de elecciones por parte de los CM. Esto significa que el proceso mencionado anteriormente es demasiado reactivo a las necesidades del sitio. Queremos considerar métodos para empoderar la autonomía de las comunidades para que tengan más voz cuando se celebran elecciones sin necesidad de esperar a que los CM encuentren tiempo para dirigirlas. Hemos realizado una investigación superficial sobre cómo otras plataformas manejan sus elecciones de moderación y encontramos algunas [prácticas atractivas en Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Requests_for_adminship). Nos encantaría explorar en asociación con la comunidad si podemos diseñar elecciones que permitan a los usuarios autodesignarse en cualquier momento y luego hacer que sus comunidades determinen en ese momento embarcarse en un proceso electoral. Nos damos cuenta de que esto es una desviación significativa del status quo actual y, por lo tanto, nos encantaría recibir comentarios de la comunidad para determinar si se podría incorporar alguna variación de esto en nuestra próxima iteración de elecciones de moderadores.

Esas son las dos piezas más importantes que estamos buscando y, por supuesto, tenemos algunas preguntas adicionales que nos interesa responder, como las siguientes:

- ¿Necesitamos diferentes tipos de elecciones (“regulares” versus “provisionales”)? ¿O podemos unificarlo en un solo procedimiento electoral? Una explicación rápida para aquellos que quizás no lo recuerden. Un moderador elegido "regularmente" es aquel que se postuló en una elección competitiva para un sitio no beta/"graduado" y fue nombrado moderador al finalizar. Un moderador "provisional" es aquel que fue elegido en una elección competitiva en un sitio beta o designado en una elección no competitiva en un sitio que no ha tenido una elección de "graduación" exitosa (ya sea porque todavía está un sitio beta, o porque no es un sitio beta pero no ha tenido una elección de “graduación” exitosa).
- ¿Tienen sentido nuestros requisitos actuales para los candidatos? ¿O es necesario revisarlos? ¿Deberían diferir según el sitio o pueden permanecer uniformes en toda la red?
- La participación en las elecciones de moderadores está disminuyendo. ¿Podemos revertir eso cambiando la forma en que se llevan a cabo las elecciones?
- En lugar de que los CM lideren las elecciones, ¿tendría más sentido crear una nueva función para facilitarlas en sitios individuales?

### Sin metas

Estas son las cosas que deliberadamente no abordamos en esta etapa. Esta iniciativa tiene como objetivo específico analizar qué podemos hacer para mejorar el proceso electoral; Algunas de las cosas que se enumeran a continuación son elementos que planeamos analizar más adelante este año o en otros momentos en el futuro. Reconocemos que estas son cosas importantes, pero no son parte de nuestro enfoque en este momento.

- Puntuación del candidato: Sabemos que esta es una parte de las elecciones que necesita actualización, pero nos gustaría tener una conversación por separado sobre esto más adelante.
- Manejo de moderadores ausentes: este proceso es algo que sabemos que necesita actualización y esperamos hacerlo en algún momento a finales de este año; incluiremos a la comunidad cuando lo abordemos.
- Incorporación del moderador: queremos analizar esto con mucha más profundidad más adelante, pero para hacerle justicia, se manejará como un proyecto propio.
- Manejo de elecciones fallidas: es posible que haya visto publicaciones en sitios que experimentaron una elección fallida. Este proceso también podría necesitar algunos ajustes. Sin embargo, en el futuro se abordará por separado.

### Próximos pasos

En las próximas semanas, planeamos formar un grupo de trabajo de miembros de la comunidad para discutir y formalizar un nuevo proceso para manejar las elecciones de moderadores. Una vez que el grupo haya desarrollado un plan sustentable dentro de los límites de los recursos de desarrollo que tenemos disponibles para esto, lo presentaremos a Meta y lo probaremos en algunos sitios voluntarios antes de implementarlo en toda la red para realizar más pruebas.

Si está interesado en participar en el grupo de trabajo, [háganoslo saber completando el formulario de Google aquí](https://forms.gle/1aXHKCbMcyX6pY7WA). Complételo antes del 12 de febrero de 2024 para ser considerado. El grupo de trabajo contará con una sala de chat que estará en modo galería para que cualquier interesado pueda seguir la conversación. También tendremos una instancia privada del equipo para discutir los cambios que al grupo le gustaría ver. **Aquellos que estén invitados a participar en el grupo de trabajo serán notificados alrededor del 13 de febrero de 2024.**

Consulte el cronograma a continuación para saber cuándo esperamos pasar a cada fase de este proceso. **Entendemos que cualquiera que desee participar lo hará de forma voluntaria, por lo que estas fechas son provisionales y estaremos encantados de ajustarlas según sea necesario.**

| Fecha | Fase |
| --- | --- |
| 13 de febrero de 2024 | Inicio del grupo de trabajo |
| 29 de febrero de 2024 | Comentarios sobre la propuesta electoral a la comunidad. |
| 14 de marzo de 2024 | Sitios de prueba anunciados |
| 1 de abril de 2024 | Período de recopilación de comentarios para los sitios de prueba |
| 15 de abril de 2024 | Actualización de MSE sobre el proyecto. |

Estamos dispuestos a repensar todo el proceso y realizar mejoras siempre que sea posible. Háganos saber si tiene preguntas o ideas adicionales que no abordamos o si tiene inquietudes sobre lo que hemos establecido aquí. Esta publicación es un lugar apropiado para dejar comentarios o ideas sobre lo que le gustaría que cambiara, incluso si no planea unirse al grupo de trabajo.

Consideraremos comentarios hasta el 13 de febrero de 2024, cuando el grupo de trabajo comience su trabajo.

Comment: Creo que ningún cargo debe ser vitalicio, me parece que hacer elecciones una vez al año es muy apresurado, creo que debe haber elecciones cada 2 años a menos que ocurra algún hecho extraordinario

Comment: Cada 2 años renovar 2 de los 4 mod (los más antiguos)

Comment: Comentar únicamente que en ningún caso esta publicación se refiere a la duración de los cargos electos. Lo que se pretende es buscar una forma de organizar las elecciones que de menos trabajo a los CM y que fomente la participación básicamente.